# Visualization on the features with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm using Python+Sklearn, and working on multivariate classification/regression. Currently I use `scatter` and `plot` in `matplotlab` and `pylab` to visualize the variable distributions with the chosen features, and such a visualization provides me a rough implication of what kinds of model I would try.

Are there other useful methods for the observation of 1 or 2 features plus their labels in a two dimensional plot? And does sklearn support something similar?

Comment: The [examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html) contain lots of plots; you might want to inspect them to learn new plotting tricks.

Comment: You can try doing PCA on the problem to collapse the data down into 2 principal components. And then plot them against the output variable. This can give you some insight into the complexity of the data distribution.